# How to easily create sequentially named vectors from the same data

Tags: r

I am trying to generate 100 samples sets from a population. Code is currently

```
sam1<-sample(population, 30, replace = T)
sam2<-sample(population, 30, replace = T)
sam3<-sample(population, 30, replace = T)
```

Since I am sampling repeatedly from the same data, is there any easier way to create 100 vectors sequentially like `sam1...sam100` vectors?

Answer (score 1):

Try `replicate` function where `population` is a `vector` or `list`

```
replicate(n = 100,sample(population, 30, replace = T))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is to put all the samples in a single list:

```
samples = list()
for (i in 1:100) {
    samples[[i]] = sample(population, 30, replace = T)
}
```

You can access individual samples easily like:

```
samples[[33]]
```